# Java Generic code

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I am new to generics. You can see I am repeating some code after knowing the exact type of `val`, `filterSmall`, `filterGreat`. I want to write generic code for comparing `val` against filter values. I could write something like this

```
  private  <T> boolean  compareAgainstFilters(T val, T filterSmall, T filterGreat) {
    if (!(filterSmall != null && filterSmall <= val)) {
        return true;
    } 

    if (!(filterGreat != null && val <= filterGreat)) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but at compile time, java wouldn't know if the `<=` operator is valid for type `T`.

I don't want to repeat the code, so how can I achieve that?

```
if (value != null) {
        switch (value.getClass().getName()) {
        case "java.lang.Long":
            Long filterSmall = (Long) filterSmaller;
            Long filterGreat = (Long) filterGreater;
            Long val = (Long) value;

            if (!(filterSmall != null && filterSmall <= val)) {
                return true;
            } 

            if (!(filterGreat != null && val <= filterGreat)) {
                return true;
            }
            break;

        case "java.lang.Float":
            Float filterSmallFloat = (Float) filterSmaller;
            Float filterGreatFloat = (Float) filterGreater;
            Float valFloat = (Float) value;

            if (!(filterSmallFloat != null && filterSmallFloat <= valFloat)) {
                return true;
            } 

            if (!(filterGreatFloat != null && valFloat <= filterGreatFloat)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have a small bug in your logic: you return `true` if `val` is greater than `filterSmall`, even if it is greater than `filterGreat`. Furthermore, you return `true` if `val` is smaller than `filterGreat`, even if it is smaller than `filterSmall`. Finally, I think you want to `return false;` if neither `if`-clauses were `true`.

Comment: How is your question specific to java 8?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there could be a better way to solve this in Java 8. Guess not.

Comment: A side note: This `switch` over the class name looks odd for me. Such type checks should be avoided in general, but I see that this can be hard with `Number` objects, so if you really really have to do such tests, you should use `if (value instanceof Float)`...

Comment: @Marco13 yeah I will take that into consideration! Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `Comparable` interface for comparing numbers, since all the wrapper classes of numeric primitives implement it :

```
  private  <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean  compareAgainstFilters(T val, T filterSmall, T filterGreat) {
    if (!(filterSmall != null && filterSmall.compareTo(val)<=0)) {
        return true;
    } 

    if (!(filterGreat != null && val.compareTo(filterGreat)<=0)) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`<T extends Comparable<T>>` restricts the types that can be used as type arguments instead of T. In this case they are required to implement `Comparable<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the `<` or `>` operators in the generic method. Normally when the variable is of type `Float` or `Long`, the compiler would accept the operator after doing automatic unboxing conversion (to get the primitive type) in the compiled code. In other words,

```
filterSmall <= val
```

is compiled to:

```
filterSmall.longValue() <= val.longValue()
```

In the generic method, there is no way for the compiler to apply unboxing conversion. The only way to perform comparison is to have the type parameter extend the `Comparable` interface, and use the `compareTo` method. Note that the types `Float`, `Long` and so on already implement this interface.